# What is the difference between a URL and a LINK?

Tags: url, browser, hyperlink, terminology

People talk about **URL**  and **LINK** as if they're different things, but they look the same to the naked eye.

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

URL is an acronym for "Uniform Resource Locator", and it is the
address that specifies the location of a resource on the Internet. A
typical URL must specify the protocol used to access the resource, the
name of the host computer on which it is located, and the path of the
resource:

```
http://www.server.com/main/folder/resource.html
```

The above URL indicates that the document `resource.html` is located at
the web server `www.server.com` where it can be found in the path
`/main/folder`.

An Hyperlink, or simply a Link, is:

> "An element in an electronic
> document that links to another place in the same document or to an
> entirely different document. Typically, you click on the hyperlink to
> follow the link."

**[Source](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/579921.html)**

Answer (score 5):

These are some URLs:

- `http://example.com/`
- `mailto:alice@example.com`
- `https://example.com/all.css`

In a document, these URLs can be *linked*. This would, typically, allow consumers to do something with this URL (by clicking on it, or automatically when opening the document, etc.), e.g.:

- visiting the page identified by the linked URL
- sending an email to the linked email address
- downloading the stylesheet referenced by the link

In an HTML document (which is the most popular, but not the only document format that can contain links), you could (for example) use the [`a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), which creates an *hyperlink* (aka. *link*) that can have a label (or anchor text) of your choice, e.g.:

- `<a href="http://example.com/">This is a link.</a>`
  `<a href="http://example.com/">http://example.com/</a>`
  `<a href="http://example.com/">http://example.net/misleading-label</a>`
- `<a href="mailto:alice@example.com">email me</a>`
  `<a href="mailto:alice@example.com">alice@example.com</a>`
- `<a href="https://example.com/all.css">A CSS file</a>`
  `<link href="https://example.com/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />`